# DHCP Relay agent not working

Tags: dhcp

I'm quite new to the DHCP Relay Agent thing, but it seems to be best solution.

So here is the deal:
DHCP server (Win 2012R2) is at 10.0.3.1/24;
ServerB (Win 2012R2) is at 10.0.3.3/24 and 10.0.2.1/24.
ClientB should get it's IP lease from DHCP server (on the 10.0.2.0/24) subnet.

So I've set up the DHCP Relay Agent on ServerB's Routing and Remote Access. The interface set is the one which is towards 10.0.2.0 net (Relay DHCP packets is checked). In the DHCP Relay Agent options I've shown the DHCP servers IP address (10.0.3.1).

Each time I try to renew ipconfig on ClientB it says that "Unable to contact your DHCP server."
I tried pinging the DHCP server both from ClientB and from ServerB - they can connect.

Any tips where to look for the problem? :(

EDIT:
Forgot to add - on the DHCP server I have two scopes: 10.0.1.0/24 (that is directly connected to the DHCP server and works) and 10.0.2.0/24 (which I'm trying to get through the relay. And the funny thing is that the IP address ClientB gets is on the same subnet but outside the scope. The gateway which is given to ClientB is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved :)

Both servers also are used as routers. On the server with DHCP role the NAT routing protocol was activated. Once the protocol was de-activated the relay works perfect.